# application stopped working with GameServices.ane

Tags: distriqt

I try to use GameServices.ane (distriqt) and when reach signIn point application stop working.

Maybe some one know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, Is there any more information you can provide? What platform you are using, which service, and the code that is failing? Most things that would cause sign in to fail are related to configuration so double check you have setup the service you are using correctly. You can check the getting started guide for more: http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.GameServices#get-started

Comment: hello. this line helped: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="**@integer/google_play_services_version**" />     You should never set the gms.version to a static number like that. It will cause issues. If the other extensions you are using require such an old version of the google play services you will run into issues. v4 is very old, they are currently up to v9.2 and infact 9.4 was released the other day which we will be updating to this week.